# p-table rowsPerPageOptions does not expand the dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng, paginator

I'm using the p-table component trying to show the paginator with the dropdown with rows per page option (rowsPerPageOptions):

```
<p-table
  [columns]="cols"
  [value]="myData"
  [paginator]="true"
  [rows]="2"
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="[1,2,3]">
```

The table shows up fine with the paginator control, but the dropdown that contains the per-page option does not expand (drop).

Here's the stackblitz link of the app - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xywt2w?file=app/provider-search/provider-search.component.html

Why does the dropdown not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,BrowserAnimationsModule ... ]
  // ...
})
```

Comment: that was exactly the issue! fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Correct form:

```
[rowsPerPageOptions]="['5', '10', '20', '50']"
```

Comment: Thanks.

Now, Per Page Option Dropdown selected.