# p-table rowsPerPageOptions dropdown terminates improperly

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am using PrimeNG's p-table with the rowsPerPageOptions set as follows

```
[rowsPerPageOptions]="[25,50,100]"
```

I can see the paginator options dropdown too, but on clicking it, the dropdown terminates abruptly on the screen.
[image: Dropdown terminating abruptly]

Edit: I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939143/p-table-rowsperpageoptions-does-not-expand-the-dropdown) answer already. It does not help as I already have the animations module imported

Comment: This is most likely an issue with the css of your surrounding box setting overflow:hidden.

Comment: @JensHabegger you are right. The parent has `overflow:hidden !important` set at some level. Is there a way to make this one overlay not hidden? I say this because I upgraded PrimeNg and started seeing these issues. The overlay properly was there previously too but wasn't causing any issues.

Comment: There are methods that enable you to bypass the overflow property of a parent, but they can be a bit hackish in nature. Judging from the screenshot, you are building some kind of grid-based dashboard with individual boxes. Are you able to override the overflow: hidden on that specific box?

Comment: I added the `overflow: visible` style to the component and turned off `overflow:hidden !important` using the browser dev tools. So I can confirm what you said is right. I need to understand the implications of the setting first and see if I can do away with it. The app I'm working on was built in the days of Angular 2. CSS added iteratively over the years is a real pain :|